# How to respond in a prompt using exec channel of JSch

Tags: ksh, exec

I need to respond to a prompt generated by a command,

for example

```
ssh hostname
```

then a password prompt appears and the script must automatically enter the password after the prompt.

I tried using read but it did not work.

I did it in shell easily but in exec, it is a challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

channel.setPty(true) did the trick